# Как правильно перехватывать нажатия клавиш в Windows Forms (C++)?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, webbrowser

На `Form` есть `DataGridView` (в нём показывается одна строка) и `WebBrowser`.

У `Form` на `Event keyDown` есть обработчик, который срабатывает на нажатие `F2`, который записывает слово в определенную ячейку. Этот же обработчик привязан к `DataGridView`.

```
private: System::Void CSV_WViewForm_KeyDown(
    System::Object^  sender,
    System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e)
    {
        if (e->KeyCode == Keys::F2)
            /*Do something*/;           
    }
```

Необходимо, чтобы нажатие на `F2` срабатывало всегда и сразу (с первого раза).
Для этого я воспользовался свойством `KeyPreview = false;` (пробовал устанавливать его в `true` - не помогало).

```
protected:
    virtual bool ProcessCmdKey(Message% msg, Keys keyData) override
    {
        if (keyData == Keys::F2)
        {
            this->dataGridView1->Focus();
            return Form::ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData);
        }
        return Form::ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData);
    }
```

Но когда [`Focus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx) находится в `WebBrowser`, `F2` не всегда срабатывает (иногда приходится нажимать `F2` дважды). Как это победить?

**Проект Windows Forms (C++, Visual Studio 2015)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если уж перехватываете ввод пользователя на уровне формы, то там его и обрабатывайте. Простой тестовый проект с эквивалентным кодом на C# показал следующее:

1. Если элемент в фокусе, все отрабатывает как надо.
2. Если элемент не в фокусе и мы предварительно на уровне формы переключаем фокус на другой элемент, то событие о нажатой клавише уходит тому элементу, который был в фокусе во время нажатия на клавишу, что в принципе логично. Отсюда и необходимость второго нажатия на клавишу, т.к. первое нажатие отрабатывает только передачу фокуса и уходит предыдущему владельцу фокуса.

**Что делать?**

Перенести всю обработку клавиш, которые перехватываются на уровне формы, в код перехвата (в `ProcessCmdKey`), чтобы не загромождать код, сделать это в виде вызова отдельных методов для каждой перехватываемой клавиши.

Изменить ваш код можно так:

```
virtual bool ProcessCmdKey(Message% msg, Keys keyData) override
    {
        if (keyData == Keys::F2)
        {
            this->dataGridView1->Focus();

            //do somthing for F2-key

            return true;
        }
        return Form::ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData);
    }
```

или через `switch - case` если клавиш много. И не забываем удалить лишние обработчики или исключить из них обработку клавиш, перехватываемых на уровне формы.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал. Все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом.

Добавляем на форму меню (если его ещё нет) - `MenuStrip`. Если меню само по себе не нужно в приложении, то скрываем его: `Visible = false`. Добавляем в меню пункт с любым названием, назначаем ему обработчик клика (в нём выполняются нужные вам действия) и главное - задаём свойству `ShortcutKeys` нужное значение: кнопку <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Теперь нажатие на F2 будет срабатывать в любом случае, какой-бы компонент ни был в фокусе.

Проверял в C#.