# Работа с radioButton'ом в C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу программу, где нужно использовать клавиши "влево" и "вправо". Нужно выбирать правильный ответ и переключать клавишей "влево" или "вправо" для перехода к другому вопросу. Все работает, только есть одна проблема, когда наживаешь клавишу с клавиатуры, она сначала переключает значение  `radioButton`'а, а уже потом переходит к другому вопросу.

Возможно ли задать какое-то свойство для  `radioButton`'а, чтобы он не реагировал на клавиатуру?

Answer (score 3):

попробуй у всех радиобаттонов установить кейдаун ивент на этот метод (не нужно его дублировать -- у всех на один и тот же метод)

```
private void radioButton1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
  {
   if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Right
    || e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Down)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
```

Пока в фокусе элемент подписанный на такой обработчик, клавиши просто игнорируются. Совсем. Никакие другие обработчики не вызываются.

Answer (score 1):

Такое В WinForms не сделать. По крайней мере, с ходу. Максимум чего можно добиться без "танцев с бубном" - отключение перехода по клавише `Tab` с помощью свойства `TabStop`. Но, оно не действует на клавиши "со стрелками".

Советую посмотреть в сторону WPF. Там возможностей больше.

Comment: и никаких танцев с бубном, виртуальные методы для того и нужны

Comment: Если форма/контейнер используется только для навигации, а если нет? Моё ИМХО, вопрос сам по себе поставлен так, что возможно несколько правильных вариантов ответов в зависимости от конкретной ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Если у клавиш со стрелками единственное назначение на форме (или контроле-контейнере), то можно перехватить и обработать их на уровне формы, не передавая события от этих клавиш вложенным контролам. Делается это довольно просто, достаточно у формы переопределить метод обработки клавиш:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            //код переключения на предыдущий вопрос
            return true;
        case Keys.Right:
            //код переключения на следующий вопрос
            return true;
        default:
            //для всех остальных клавиш оставляем базовую обработку
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Есть еще одно альтернативное решение с использованием `MenuStrip`, оно описано в этом **[ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555475/198316)**. Если в вашей программе используется меню, то этот вариант возможно будет интересен.