# _getch winforls label

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

### Что не так?

```
int code = _getch();
this->label1->Text = code;
```

Ошибка: *E1767  невозможно вызвать функцию "System::Windows::Forms::Label::Text::set" с данным списком аргументов*

Comment: Не так то, что вы пытаетесь в качестве текста установить число без преобразования к строке?

Comment: this->label1->Text = System::Int16(code).ToString();
Пробовал это, не подошло ,может вы подскажете?

Comment: `getch` не имеет смысла в приложении WinForms. Забудьте об этой функции.

Comment: мне нужно сделать программу, которая будет выводить код последней нажатой кнопки, как тогда это сделать?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554844/Как-правильно-перехватывать-нажатия-клавиш-в-windows-forms-c?noredirect=1&lq=1