# Не работает нажатие клавиш c# windowsforms

Tags: c#, winforms, клавиатура, keydown, keypress

Сколько не добавляю разные обработчики событий, клавиши все равно не срабатывают. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина и как исправить баг.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int pipeSpeed;
    int gravity = 15;
    int score = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void gameTimeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pFluppy.Top += gravity;
        
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pFluppy.Focus();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            gravity -= 15;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            gravity = 15;
        }
    }

    private void pFluppy_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: А откуда вы знаете, что клавиши не срабатывают? Отладкой смотрели? Повесьте хоть какую-нибудь печать в консоль на события. И события сами висят на кнопках, вы не просто методы создали с такими названиями, но и привязали их на события?

Comment: Что еще есть на форме, кроме обработчиков событий? На 100% уверен что нарисован какой-то интерфейс и в фокусе находится какой-то контрол, типа textbox, который и перехватывает на себя все клавиши. Текущий продемонстрированный код не позволяет увидеть проблему

Comment: и это еще почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555402/198316 так оно надежнее будет, чем в событиях формы

Comment: @rdorn В коде формы есть настройка, с которой контролы не должны мешать обрабатывать клавиши. Дело в чём-то другом.

Comment: @CrazyElf увы, это только в теории, я уже спотыкался об это

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что Form1_KeyDown и Form1_KeyUp - это обработчики одноимённых событий. Тогда получается, что по нажатию пробела гравитация уменьшается на 15, а потом по отпусканию устанавливается в 15, то есть в результате не изменяется.

Comment: Вот теперь похоже на правду, но услышать бы хоть какую-то реакцию от того, кто вопрос задал. Непонятен сценарий использования. Может так и задумано - пока клавиша нажата, гравитация меньше. А может и нет.

Comment: Только не увеличивается, а строго 15 становится.

Comment: Удалось справиться с проблемой?